# Parents child threads not exiting properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

Need a little help regarding multithreading. I am doing some computation in separate threads in unity and rendering the result when all threads are completed.

Below is structure of my code.

```
         Thread 1
    |                |
Thread 1.1       Thread 1.2
    |                |
Thread 1.1.2.1   Thread 1.2.1.1
Thread 1.1.2.2   Thread 1.2.2.2
...              ...
```

Every time Thread 1.1 and its child (Thread 1.1.2.1..) exits properly using Join() but this is not the case with Thread 1.2; Thread 1.2.1.1.. exits without completing the code block. It looks like Join() on childThreadList is not blocking current thread in case of Thread 1.2.

Code is simple making blocks of large list and process them in parallel. I was previously having same issue that Thread 1.1 and Thread 1.2 exits in midway; reason was they were sharing same variable values when on .Start(). I make sure this is not the reason now.

Is there anything I am mistaking or missing, please advice.

Example code:

```
//Running in Thread 1; started from main()
private unsafe void AddSurfaceData()
{
    float* points;
    int points_length;

    float* colours;
    int colours_length;

    System.UIntPtr *indices;
    int indices_length;

    //set references for points, colours, indices, points_length, colours_length, indices_length

    ProcessTriangles(points, indices, colours, indices_length);
}

private unsafe void ProcessTriangles(float* points, System.UIntPtr *indices, float* colours, int indices_length)
{
    List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();

    int currLength = 65535;
    int initialLength = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        if(currLength < indices_length)
        {
            int from = initialLength;
            int to = currLength;

            //Add surfaceData
            int surfaceIndex = surfaceData.Count-1;

            //Start thread from initialLength to currLength 
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => AddTriangle(from, to, indices, points, colours, surfaceIndex));
            threadList.Add(thread);
            thread1Count++;
            thread.Name = "Thread 1."+thread1Count;
            thread.Start();

            initialLength = currLength;
            currLength += 65535;
        }

        else
        {
            int from = initialLength;
            int to = indices_length;

            //Add surfaceData
            surfaceData.Add(new ScanManager.SurfaceData(new Vector3[to-from], new Color[to-from], new int[to-from]));
            int surfaceIndex = surfaceData.Count-1;

            //Start thread from initialLength to indices_length
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => AddTriangle(from, to, indices, points, colours, surfaceIndex));
            threadList.Add(thread);
            thread1Count++;
            thread.Name = "Thread 1."+thread1Count;
            thread.Start();

            break;
        }
    }

    foreach(Thread thread in threadList)
    {
       thread.Join();
    }
}

private unsafe void AddTriangle(int fromLength, int toLength, System.UIntPtr *indices, float* points, float* colours, int surfaceIndex)
{
    List<Thread> childThreadList = new List<Thread>();

    int initialLength = fromLength;
    int currLength = 21000+initialLength;
    int index = surfaceIndex;
    int indicesLength = toLength;

    while(true)
    {
        if(currLength < indicesLength)
        {
            int from = initialLength;
            int to = currLength;

            //Start thread from initialLength to currLength 
            Thread childThread = new Thread(() => AddTriangleData(from, to, indices, points, colours, index));
            childThreadList.Add(childThread);
            thread2Count++;
            childThread.Name = Thread.CurrentThread.Name+".2."+thread2Count;
            childThread.Start();

            initialLength = currLength;
            currLength += 21000;
        }

        else
        {
            int from = initialLength;
            int to = indicesLength;

            //Start thread from initialLength to indices_length
            Thread childThread = new Thread(() => AddTriangleData(from, to, indices, points, colours, index));
            childThreadList.Add(childThread);
            thread2Count++;
            childThread.Name = Thread.CurrentThread.Name+".2."+thread2Count;
            childThread.Start();

            break;
        }
    }

   foreach(Thread childThread in childThreadList)
   {
     childThread.Join();
   }
}

private unsafe void AddTriangleData(int fromLength, int toLength, System.UIntPtr *indices, float* points, float* colours, int surfaceIndex)
{
    for(int i=fromLength; i<toLength; i+=3)
    {
        //AddTriangleVertex (i)
        //AddTriangleVertex (i+1)
        //AddTriangleVertex (i+2)
    }
}
```